# What is the minimum value of $\frac{a_1}{a_2} + \frac{a_2}{a_3} +\cdots + \frac{a_n}{a_1} $

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n$ are positive real numbers.

**Question:** what is the minimum value of
$$\frac{a_1}{a_2} + \frac{a_2}{a_3} +\cdots + \frac{a_n}{a_1} $$

**Thought:** I have no clue how to proceed. Tried some standard inequalities but in vain.

Comment: I presume the next-to-last term is $\dfrac{a_{n-1}}{a_n}$?

Comment: yup @john wayland

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the inequality of arithmetic and geometric means we have that  $$\frac{a_{1}}{a_{2}} + \frac{a_{2}}{a_{3}}+\dots +\frac{a_{n}}{a_{1}} \geq n \, \left( \frac{a_{1}\cdot a_{2}\cdot \dots \cdot a_{n-1} \cdot a_{n}}{a_{2}\cdot a_{3} \dots \cdot a_{n} \cdot a_{1}}\right)^{1/n} = n $$

Comment: you left no work for the OP -- doing their homework for them is not exactly the point of the site...

Comment: How do you know for certain that it was a homework?

Comment: I don't -- but the chances are quite high. Neither do you know that it wasn't -- so why take a chance at spoiling the learning process? In such cases, I would rather give a  hint, or even a detailed hint -- but solving the whole thing without the OP showing *any* effort on the problem whatsoever is beyond my comfort level.

Answer (score 7):

You seek $n$ times the arithmetic mean of positive reals of known geometric mean, so by the AM-GM inequality we obtain the minimum when each fraction is equal to that geometric mean. I'll leave the rest as an exercise.